# Resolving principal id in Azure AD to User,Service

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-rbac

I am trying to resolve a list of principal ids into the details like name of the user/service. I have the following code -

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

TENANT = 'something.onmicrosoft.com'
TENANT_ID = '...'
CLIENT_ID = '...'
SECRET = '...'
List_of_Principal_IDs= ['...','...']
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    secret=SECRET,
    tenant=TENANT_ID,
    resource="https://graph.windows.net"
)
client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, TENANT)
```

I tried following the advice on on one of the [stackoverflow pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64688046/how-do-you-turn-a-principal-id-into-a-username-using-the-azure-python-sdk) but I am running into errors (see following). Any guidance on how I can resolve these principal ids to human understandable format would be appreciated.

```
users = client.users.list(
         filter=f"principal_id eq '{List_of_Principal_IDs[0]}'"
     )
test = users.next()
```

Error -

> azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Property 'principal_id' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.

```
users = client.objects.get_objects_by_object_ids(List_of_Principal_IDs[0])
user = users.next()
```

Error -

> msrest.exceptions.SerializationError: Unable to build a model: Unable
> to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no
> attribute 'get', DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to
> object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Property
> 'principal_id' does not exist as a declared property or extension
> property.

About this error, `principal_id` does not exist in the [properties of users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). If I don't misunderstand, the `principal_id` means the `Object ID` of the user. But Object_id doesn't support `filter`, you need to use [get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.operations.usersoperations?view=azure-python#get-upn-or-object-id--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) method instead of [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.operations.usersoperations?view=azure-python#list-filter-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) method.

```
user = client.users.get(upn_or_object_id)
```

---

> msrest.exceptions.SerializationError: Unable to build a model: Unable
> to deserialize to object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no
> attribute 'get', DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to
> object: type, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

[get_objects_by_object_ids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.operations.objectsoperations?view=azure-python#get-objects-by-object-ids-parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) needs parameters of [`GetObjectsParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.models.getobjectsparameters?view=azure-python) class, but not just a list.

```
objects = graphrbac_client.objects.get_objects_by_object_ids({
    'object_ids': [list of object ids],
    'types': [list of object types]
})
```

Comment: The second method fails when converting the objects returned to list if you searched for the object ids of deleted objects. Since I usually do 1000+ at a time would it usually is very slow to do them individually. Any work arounds that you can think of?