# AttributeError: 'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I'm using python sdk to query application insights using `azure-applicationinsights==0.1.1`.
Here is my code:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.applicationinsights import ApplicationInsightsDataClient
from azure.applicationinsights.models import QueryBody

def query_app_insights():
    query = 'myEvents | take 10'
    application = 'my-app'
    creds = DefaultAzureCredential()
    client = ApplicationInsightsDataClient(creds)
    result = client.query.execute(application, QueryBody(query=query))
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'
```

also tried:

```py
    creds = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id='something',
                                   client_id='something',
                                   client_secret='something')
    client = ApplicationInsightsDataClient(creds)
```

It gives me the same error.

also I tried:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.applicationinsights import ApplicationInsightsDataClient
from azure.applicationinsights.models import QueryBody
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

def query_app_insights():
    query = 'myEvents | take 10'
    application = 'my-app'
    creds = ServicePrincipalCredentials(tenant='something',
                                        client_id='something',
                                        secret='something')
    client = ApplicationInsightsDataClient(creds)
    result = client.query.execute(application, QueryBody(query=query))
```

It complaints about my secret, but it is correct.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does this post help fix the issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384092/exception-attributeerror-defaultazurecredential-object-has-no-attribute-sig

Comment: Nope. It results in this error: `azure.applicationinsights.models.error_response_py3.ErrorResponseException: (InvalidTokenError) The provided authentication is not valid for this resource`

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session':

This error occurs frequently these days and I've also faced this couple of times. It actually means that "*no signed session available for the given tenant*".

After I've done a workaround, I found there is some issue addressed here with the SDK management libraries.

***The [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/authentication-overview?tabs=cmd) class has been modified, and it no longer has the'signed session' attribute in few versions. To handle this, the most recent versions of the management libraries should be upgraded.***

***Need to check & resolve:***

- Installed the latest versions of the modules when you are importing in  `Python` code.

  ```
   azure-identity 1.12.0
   azure-applicationinsights 0.1.1
  ```
- Selected `python 3.10` interpreter in visual studio code and ran the same code as yours in a virtual environment.
- Created a [virtual env](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) and ran the project.

  ```py
    py -m venv env
  .\env\Scripts\activate
  ```
- Sometimes `requirements.txt` file will not get properly configured, In that scenario also you may face this error.

  To avoid that, Freeze the requirements by using terminal:
  `pip freeze requirements.txt`

*After meeting all the above conditions, I tried in my environment and was able to proceed without any attribute errors.*

***Output:***

[image]

*Alternatively, I tried connecting with* `clientsecretcredential` *by registering to a new Application in* `AzureAD`.

**Note**: Prefer to create a new registration instead of using old registrations as `client_secrets` might be expired.

```py
TENANT_ID = '<TENANT_ID>'
CLIENT_ID = '<CLIENT_ID>'
CLIENT_SECRET = '<CLIENT_SECRET>'
SUBSCRIPTION_ID = '<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>'
from  azure.identity  import  ClientSecretCredential
from  azure.mgmt.keyvault  import  KeyVaultManagementClient
credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=TENANT_ID, client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
credentialskeyvault = KeyVaultManagementClient(credentials, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
print ("Logged")
```

***Output:***

[image]

***To determine the precise status:***

I simply deleted specific "*rights/permissions*" from my application in `AzureAD` and tested whether it threw an error when logged in.

*Why because*?

This error is usually thrown only after the user logged in. It states that the `defaultazurecredential` object was running without problem.

[image]

*If the issue still persists, then you can wrap credentials by installing `msrestazure` module and create a* [credentialwrapperclass](https://gist.github.com/lmazuel/cc683d82ea1d7b40208de7c9fc8de59d) *detailed by* @lmazuel.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried all of these and none of them worked.

Comment: @max you got any solution ?

Comment: @omar sorry for late reply. You can use this package to work around it: github.com/kouroshparsa/az_sights