# Getting "AttributeError: 'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'" using the azure.identity python package

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk-python

My code to read from the `Log Analytics Workspace` fails with the titular error.

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.loganalytics import LogAnalyticsDataClient
from azure.loganalytics.models import QueryBody
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

# Replace these variables with your actual values
workspace_id = 'ABCDE'
query = """ddex_CL
| take 100
"""

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

client = LogAnalyticsDataClient(credential)
query_body = QueryBody(query=query)
body=query_body)
response = client.query(workspace_id, body=query_body).execute()
for row in response.tables[0].rows:
    print(row)
```

Note: there are similar question here: [Exception: AttributeError: 'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session' using Azure Function and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384092/exception-attributeerror-defaultazurecredential-object-has-no-attribute-sig) .  The most upvoted answer says

> As of May 2022, all SDKs have been re-released with native support for azure-identity

But I still encounter the error even though installing the latest version via:

```
pip3 install azure-loganalytics azure-identity

pip show azure-loganalytics
Name: azure-loganalytics
Version: 0.1.1

$pip show azure-identity
Name: azure-identity
Version: 1.14.0
```

Another similar question is here:  [AttributeError: 'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778698/attributeerror-defaultazurecredential-object-has-no-attribute-signed-session) . But I do already have the lastest library version installed.

Are there any other library or code changes that are needed?

Comment: If you want code with azure.monitor.query you can open new question or I can post an answer with it?

Comment: @RithwikBojja  I am going in circles with these api's . Can't get them to work, documentation is mixed between different versions

Comment: using azure.monitor.query it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

azure-loganalytics is no longer maintained (see https://pypi.org/project/azure-loganalytics/), and has been replaced by https://pypi.org/project/azure-monitor-query. This package will support azure-identity.

For more questions, do not hesitate to go on the Github repo of the SDK: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

(I'm the manager of the Azure Python SDK team at Microsoft)